# Proving that a group is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose we have a group $G$ with $|G| = 10$. How do I prove that if its center $Z$ is nontrivial, then $G$ is abelian? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the center is nontrivial but $G$ is nonabelian then the center must have order $2$ or $5.$ But then $G/Z$ has order 5 or 2, hence must be cyclic.